# Enable 'zoom out' from initial viewport

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, viewport

This is an issue with handling the viewport meta tag on my Android Chrome browser (Not tested in other browsers).

I want a web page that can be zoomed OUT, not just zoomed IN.

If I use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
```

I can zoom out to a scale of 0.5 (and 0.5 is the 'initial' zoom, as I would have expected)

But if I use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=0.5">
```

I can't zoom out past the initial scale.

Have I misunderstood the meaning of initial-scale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser won't let you zoom out further than the content width. You can't zoom out to see things "beyond" your content.

Since you specify `width=device-width`, the page will use your device width as the layout width. Say, for example, you have a screen that's 400px wide. Without giving your elements an explicit size (e.g. `width: 1000px`), your content will be 400px wide. Thus, the minimum scale factor you can zoom out to is 1 (400px / 400px). If you add an element that has `width: 800px`, the content will now be 800px wide so the minimum scale will be 0.5.

So you need to make your content wider. Either make your content wider explicitly, or use an explicit width in your meta tag, e.g. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=800, initial-scale=1">`.

Also, note that without initial-scale, the browser will load your page zoomed out as far as it can.

Comment: Thanks for the information. When you use a fixed body with 100vh and 100vw, and inside you have a fixed DIV which is holding flexible content, the problem is that you cannot know the width needed. In this case it would be helpful to define this #div for the `width=device-width` directive. But probably Javascript is needed for this. – Here is one way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26533251/1066234

Comment: "The browser won't let you zoom out further than the content width". That's very inconvenient: in some cases in landscape mode I really need (myself/the user) to be able to zoom out past the content width. How do we persuade Google to modify Chrome so as to allow for that?